# Match date in dataframe with closest date in a list in R

Tags: r, date, geospatial, lubridate

I have a data frame with a list of dates. I also have a list of reference dates in the form of a vector. I have created a reproducible data frame and vector. You can ignore the 'r' object, except for creating the dateframe.

```
i=500;j=500;n=50
r <- do.call(stack, replicate(n,raster(matrix(runif(i*j), i, j))))
( dates <- seq(as.Date("2020/10/23"), by = 16, length.out = 20) ) 

s <- as(sampleRandom(r[[1]], 100, sp=TRUE), "sf")
df <-  as.data.frame(s)
df$date <- sample(dates, nrow(s), replace=TRUE)
```

I want to find the nearest date in each data frame row to the nearest vector date. Then return the closest vector date in a new column in the data frame.

For reference, I will use this to match the vector date to the corresponding raster in a raster stack and extract based on the date. This is why 's' is originally in 'sf' type and I have the 'r' object too.

Comment: I don't understand yet. `df$date` takes a random date from the vector `dates`. Isn't that already the nearest date from the vector by virtue of being identical? What would the output look like? (This might be easier to demonstrate if you can add `set.seed(0)` or similar to your code so ours gets the same result.)

Answer (score 3):

Nearest elements in one vector to elements in another calls for `` `-` `` in `outer` to get distances. Then take the `abs`olute values and find `which.min` in row of the resulting matrix to get indices `md` of smallest distances.

```
(md <- outer(v2, v1, `-`) |> abs() |> apply(1, which.min))
# [1]  1  7 12 16 16 17 20 25 27 28
```

*Check:*

```
data.frame(v2, v1[md])
#            v2      v1.d.
# 1  2022-10-06 2022-10-07
# 2  2023-01-19 2023-01-19
# 3  2023-02-25 2023-02-25
# 4  2023-04-17 2023-05-02
# 5  2023-05-05 2023-05-02
# 6  2023-05-16 2023-05-18
# 7  2023-07-21 2023-07-26
# 8  2023-08-22 2023-08-19
# 9  2023-09-15 2023-09-10
# 10 2023-09-22 2023-09-21
```

---

*Data:*

```
dt <- seq.Date(Sys.Date() - 365, Sys.Date(), 'day')
set.seed(42)
(v1 <- sample(dt, 30) |> sort())
(v2 <- sample(dt, 10) |> sort())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is very useful code!

Comment: @jwell123 You're welcome. Please consider to [accept answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/6574038).

Answer (score 1):

To implement this, you must decide whether to look for the
closest date in the past, future, or both. If you choose both, you’ll need to
decide what to do if two dates have the same distance.

Here are two approaches.

1. Do a `left_join()` and use `closest()` in `join_by()`.
2. Write a custom function to find the closest date.

## Data preparatation for both approaches.

```r
# Boiled down example of what you describe in your question.

library(tidyverse)

dates <- seq(as.Date("2020/10/23"),
             by = 16,
             length.out = 20)
dates2 <- sample(dates, 10)
df <- tibble(date = sample(dates, 30, replace = TRUE))
```

## 1. `closest()` and `join_by()`

This look for the closest date in one direction.

```r
ref_df <-
  tibble(date_vector = dates2)

left_join(df, ref_df,
          by = join_by(closest(date <= date_vector)),
          keep = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 30 × 2
#>    date       date_vector
#>    <date>     <date>     
#>  1 2020-12-26 2020-12-26 
#>  2 2020-10-23 2020-11-08 
#>  3 2021-07-22 2021-08-23 
#>  4 2021-03-16 2021-03-16 
#>  5 2021-04-17 2021-05-03 
#>  6 2021-04-17 2021-05-03 
#>  7 2021-04-17 2021-05-03 
#>  8 2021-04-17 2021-05-03 
#>  9 2021-01-11 2021-03-16 
#> 10 2020-12-26 2020-12-26 
#> # ℹ 20 more rows
```

If we want to look in both directions we could do this:

```r
left_join(df, ref_df,
          by = join_by(closest(date <= date_vector)),
          keep = TRUE) |>
  left_join(ref_df,
            by = join_by(closest(date >= date_vector)),
            keep = TRUE) |>
  # Reverse the order of date_vector.x and date_vector.y in the
  # coalesce() call to decide which direction to prefer.
  mutate(closest_date = coalesce(date_vector.x, date_vector.y))
#> # A tibble: 30 × 4
#>    date       date_vector.x date_vector.y closest_date
#>    <date>     <date>        <date>        <date>      
#>  1 2020-12-26 2020-12-26    2020-12-26    2020-12-26  
#>  2 2020-10-23 2020-11-08    NA            2020-11-08  
#>  3 2021-07-22 2021-08-23    2021-07-06    2021-08-23  
#>  4 2021-03-16 2021-03-16    2021-03-16    2021-03-16  
#>  5 2021-04-17 2021-05-03    2021-03-16    2021-05-03  
#>  6 2021-04-17 2021-05-03    2021-03-16    2021-05-03  
#>  7 2021-04-17 2021-05-03    2021-03-16    2021-05-03  
#>  8 2021-04-17 2021-05-03    2021-03-16    2021-05-03  
#>  9 2021-01-11 2021-03-16    2020-12-26    2021-03-16  
#> 10 2020-12-26 2020-12-26    2020-12-26    2020-12-26  
#> # ℹ 20 more rows
```

## 2. Custom function

The custom function looks in both directions.

```r
# Function that finds the closest date in a vector of dates.
find_closest_date <- function(date, date_vector)
{
  date_vector <- unique(date_vector)
  diffs <- abs(date - date_vector)
  
  # Two dates in date_vector can have the same distance to date, by adding
  # `[1]` we pick whichever comes first in date_vector.
  date_vector[diffs == min(diffs)][1]
}

# Test the function for one date.
find_closest_date(dates[1], dates2)
#> [1] "2020-11-08"

# Apply function to all dates.

df |>
  mutate(closest_date = map(date, find_closest_date, dates2) |>
           list_simplify())
#> # A tibble: 30 × 2
#>    date       closest_date
#>    <date>     <date>      
#>  1 2020-12-26 2020-12-26  
#>  2 2020-10-23 2020-11-08  
#>  3 2021-07-22 2021-07-06  
#>  4 2021-03-16 2021-03-16  
#>  5 2021-04-17 2021-05-03  
#>  6 2021-04-17 2021-05-03  
#>  7 2021-04-17 2021-05-03  
#>  8 2021-04-17 2021-05-03  
#>  9 2021-01-11 2020-12-26  
#> 10 2020-12-26 2020-12-26  
#> # ℹ 20 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is very useful code!

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider upvoting/accepting.